# How to set Motion Layout customColorValue programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I am using the following Motion Scene in a MotionLayout:

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        app:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
        app:duration="1000"/>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/statusResult2">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="textColor"
                app:customColorValue="#000000"/>
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/statusResult2">
            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="textColor"
                app:customColorValue="#008000"/>
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

As you can see I am animating the text colour of a text view from black to green using CustomAttribute.

However, I would actually like to set the value of `app:customColorValue` in the `@id/end` ConstraintSet programmatically from the Activity, assigning it different values based on a condition.

I cannot seem to find anything online that directly addresses how to set a custom attribute like this programmatically. There are some resources which mention using the layout's getConstraintSet method, but from there I am struggling to successfully modify the customColorValue attribute. For example I tried something like this (which does not yet implement any conditions):

```
binding.motionLayout.getConstraintSet(R.id.end).apply { this.customAttributeSet.put("customColorValue", "#008000")
}
```

But the compiler complains because the value field requires a ConstraintAttribute, not a string, and I don't know how to work with that, nor can I find good documentation about it.

Does anyone have some advice on how to programmatically set a customColorValue in a ConstraintSet?

P.S. I'm new to Android Development

P.P.S. My Activity looks like this:

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailBinding
    private lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.title = "Download Result Details"
        notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java) as NotificationManager

        binding.fileNameResult.text = intent.getStringExtra("fileName")

        if(intent.getStringExtra("result").equals(DownloadResults.PASSED.description)){
            binding.statusResult.text = DownloadResults.PASSED.description
        } else {
            binding.statusResult.text = DownloadResults.FAILED.description
            binding.statusResult.setTextColor(Color.RED)

        }

        notificationManager.cancel()

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply{
                this.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                startActivity(this)
            }
        }

//        binding.motionLayout.getConstraintSet(R.id.end).apply {
//            this.customAttributeSet.put("customColorValue", "#008000")
//        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach with custom attributeSet is the correct one.
But you need to update the motionLayout.updateState(R.id.end, this)
Especially if it is in the current transition.
You may need to requestlayout() as well.